# Dollar sign with txfonts and fontenc

Tags: fonts, spacing, symbols, bold, font-encodings

I have a strange problem with the dollar sign ($) and `\textbf{}` when using the `txfonts` and `fontenc` packages. The dollar sign has a space after it. Both packages are required to reproduce the problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\textbf{\$500}\\
\$500
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Why is this? And what is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my testing perhaps there are some problems with the bold dollar symbol in T1 encoding TX fonts but I do not really know the detailed mechanism. Anyway, to switch to OT1 encoding fonts temporarily does work as a non-optimal remedy.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\$}{{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\textdollar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\textbf{\$500}\\
\$500 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's a bug in the TXfonts distribution. When the bold font metrics were built the dollar (character 36, octal 44) received the information for the ampersand (character 38, octal 46), as it is evident from the property list files derived from `t1xb.tfm` and `txb.tfm` (the fonts used for boldface in the T1 and OT1 encodings respectively). What happens because of this bug is that TeX prints a dollar sign, but reserves for it the same space it would for an ampersand. The difference is 3.33pt, so it resembles an interword space.

### From `t1xb.pl`

```
(CHARACTER O 44
   (CHARWD R 0.833)
   (CHARHT R 0.681999)
   (CHARDP R 0.0135)
   )
(CHARACTER O 45
   (CHARWD R 1.0)
   (CHARHT R 0.681999)
   (CHARDP R 0.0135)
   )
(CHARACTER O 46
   (CHARWD R 0.833)
   (CHARHT R 0.681999)
   (CHARDP R 0.0135)
   )
```

### From `txb.pl`

```
(CHARACTER O 44
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.0975)
   )
(CHARACTER O 45
   (CHARWD R 1.0)
   (CHARHT R 0.686)
   (CHARDP R 0.0135)
   )
(CHARACTER O 46
   (CHARWD R 0.833)
   (CHARHT R 0.686)
   (CHARDP R 0.0175)
   )
```

A cure is to undeclare the `\textdollar` command in T1 encoding.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\UndeclareTextCommand{\textdollar}{T1}

\begin{document}
\bfseries\$5
\end{document}
```

The developer of the NewTX fonts is active and maybe he can think to a solution for the problem at least for the `newtxtext` package if not for the original TXfonts.

Comment: Comprehensive answer to the first question, but I'll give credit to the other answer for a solution that only requires an extra line in the preamble (i.e. doesn't require changes throughout the document).